# Flask- Following tutorial to the t, but my web page is getting a 'Not Found'. More details below

Tags: python, flask

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqhxxeeTbu0&ab_channel=TechWithTim 7:35

I'm at this point in he video with no difference to his code as far as I can tell. I input the address with / and I get the home page, but when I input /home or anything following /, I get the 404 error. Shouldn't the user page allow me to input something following the / and display it?

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "Hello! This is the main page <h1>HELLO<h1>"

@app.route("/<name>")
def user(name):
  return f"Hello {name}!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

This change makes it work, but I have no idea why...

```
from markupsafe import escape   
@app.route("/<name>") 
def user(name):   
return f"Hello {escape(name)}!"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CldEz.jpg

Comment: when you visit 127.0.0.1:5000/home, it should and is displaying Hello home! the code works perfectly.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mz8N1ED

Comment: The code as provided in the question is working correctly on my end, what is the version of python and flask you are using?

Comment: Flask==2.0.1      C:\Users\Dante>python --version
Python 3.9.5

Comment: ```from markupsafe import escape   @app.route("/<name>")
def user(name):
  return f"Hello {escape(name)}!"``` This change makes it work, but I have no idea why...

Comment: Your provided code works fine when I run it. Try updating `flask`